How to use reflect.Value to unmarshal JSON
I'm reading JSON from a HTTP request. The JSON object is a slice of Account structs
In case there is a typo or error in the JSON I want to parse the JSON and return a useful error to the client
First I use []jsontext.Value to separate/isolate the Account structs and after that I unmarshal each Account struct to check for semantic errors
In the below code the first object property Account.name is misspelled as Account.name_ to trigger the parse_semantic_errors() function
The following error is returned when unmarshalling each item of the slice

json: cannot unmarshal Go value of type reflect.Value

How to use input := elem.Index(0) from the reflection to unmarshal each item in the slice?
https://go.dev/play/p/zULGB353sxW
package main

import (
  "errors"
  "fmt"
  "reflect"

  "github.com/go-json-experiment/json"
  "github.com/go-json-experiment/json/jsontext"
)

type Account struct {
  Name  *string `json:"name"`
  Email *string `json:"email"`
}

func main() {
  inputs := []Account{}
  err := parse_json(&inputs)
  if err != nil {
    return
  }
  for i, entry := range inputs {
    fmt.Println(i, *entry.Name, *entry.Email)
  }
}

func parse_json(inputs any) error {
  b := []byte(`[{"name_":"user1","email":"email1"},{"name":"user2","email":"email2"}]`)
  err := json.Unmarshal(b, &inputs, json.RejectUnknownMembers(true))
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err:", err)
    var serr *json.SemanticError
    if errors.As(err, &serr) {
      parse_semantic_errors(b, inputs)
      return serr
    }
  }
  return err
}

func parse_semantic_errors(b []byte, inputs any) {
  fmt.Println("parsing semantic error")
  
  elem := reflect.ValueOf(inputs).Elem()
  if elem.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
    fmt.Println("Input is not a slice")
    return
  }
  
  // First object in inputs slice
  input := elem.Index(0)
  fmt.Println("first item in inputs slice:", input)
  
  body, serr := get_request_body_slice(b)
  if serr != nil {
    fmt.Println("err:", serr)
    return
  }
  fmt.Println("jsontext slice:", body)
  
  for _, b := range body {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &input, json.RejectUnknownMembers(true)); err != nil {
      fmt.Println("err:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(input)
  }
}

func get_request_body_slice(b []byte) ([]jsontext.Value, error) {
  var body []jsontext.Value
  if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &body); err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Request body must be an array")
  }
  return body, nil
}


Call the Interface method.

@Volker Thanks. Create an answer :)

Create a slice of the required length. Unmarshal into each slice element.
slice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.TypeOf(inputs).Elem(), len(body), len(body))
reflect.ValueOf(inputs).Elem().Set(slice)
for i, b := range body {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, slice.Index(i).Addr().Interface(), json.RejectUnknownMembers(true)); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(slice.Index(i))
}

